# Making Monit network namespace aware

Tags: linux, monit

Need some help with Monit.
Version - 5.25.1

Is there a way to make Monit monitor network interfaces which are on different network namespaces than the network namespace where Monit itself is running?

Example:

I have two network namespaces on my system:

```
1. Global - having eth0 interface.
2. Management - having eth1 interface.
```

The Monit process itself is running on "Management" namespace, with configurations like,

`check network global interface eth0
       mode passive
check network management interface eth1
      mode passive`

So, with the above configurations, Monit is unable to find "eth0" interface. Is there any way to make Monit namespace aware?

Comment: I don't think Monit can handle namespace itself, you have to handle it externally

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it. Is there a way to handle it externally without running multiple instances of Monit (one in each namespace).